OAuth in Twiiter API v2 search recent endpoint not authenticating
I am not sure about why does my call doesn't work, even if I already did all the things the documentation shows for the rtweet library. Need some help, pretty sure it somenthing very obvious that I am missing, but I am really lost
#install.packages("rtweet")
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rtweet)
Sys.setenv(BEARER_TOKEN = "bearer token")
bearer_token <- "bearer token"
headers <- c(`Authorization` = sprintf('Bearer %s', bearer_token))
keywords <- "(debate OR debates OR monterrey)"
endpoint <- "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent"
client <- rtweet_client(client_id = "client id",
                        client_secret = "client secret",
                        app = "myapp")# here I have doubts about which is the one that comes here
client_as(client)

a <- tweet_search_recent(query = keywords)


Also adding a couple images to understand the authentication settings.
Image

Do you have a monthly paid for X API subscription? Searching for tweets isn't free.

Yes I have the paid developer subscription, I ran it in postman and it worked, that's why I'm looking for a my mistake in R

What exactly does "doesn't work" mean in this case? Are you getting an error? If so, what exactly is the error you are getting?

In R, I run the tweet_search_recent function and I get this:
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Then it opens up my web browser, and it sends me to the twitter web page, where it asks me to log in (to my developer account) and I get this:
Something went wrong you weren't able to give access to the app. go back and try logging in again.

I learned that is not necessary to use the OAuth for the recent search endpoint, so I did it with the bearer token through a GET from the httr library. This is the code:
headers <- c(`Authorization` = sprintf('Bearer %s', bearer_token))    
a <- GET(url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=%28debate+OR+debates+OR+monterrey%29+lang%3Aes&expansions=geo.place_id",
add_headers(.headers = headers))

And then just parse the results
